# Como faço para fazer esse script funcionar no meu blogger

Tags: javascript, html

quero fazer esse javascript funcionar no meu blogger .

o link dele é :https://jsfiddle.net/xuuj2qv4/

oque faço para fazer esse sistema funcionar no meu blogger?

Comment: [Central de Ajuda do Blogger](https://support.google.com/blogger/?hl=pt-BR#topic=3339243) creio que tenha tudo o que você precisa saber.

Comment: tenho,não como coloco ele para funcionar no blogger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que você deve inserir no final do código HTML a tag script, com o codigo javascript dentro, ex:

```
<script>
var button = document.querySelector(".b1");
var button2 = document.querySelector(".b2");

button.onclick = function() {
 window.open('www.google.com', '_blank');
 button2.style.display = "block";}
</script>
```

Comment: muito obrigado!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @MinelopsMl essa resposta foi a solução para sua questão? Então você pode aceitá-la, essa é a melhor maneira de dizer obrigado no site

Comment: não tem essa opção aqui